# Heroku deployment - Path not found

Tags: node.js, postgresql, heroku, path

I'm trying to deploy my app to heroku, but when deployment is done it just throws "Internal Sever Error"

Here's a gist of the error logs from heroku dashboard
https://gist.github.com/gerardomanllo/e4bdbf1e0ffa6dc70fed72cae4914899

The core problem I believe is the routing. Although, the app works flawlessly locally, so I believe there is some config gone wrong in this one.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

Github repo
https://github.com/gerardomanllo/bloccit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your code is throwing an error based on the logs you posted

```
Error: secret option required for sessions
```

Is the secret stored in an env variable locally and not on heroku?